# Unable to change text font in for loop with data from a returned array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to change the font color using an "if" statement if it meets that criteria. I have tried NSAttributedString and NSMutableAttributedString but cannot find anything to accomplish what I want to do. I am using the print statement to show the for loop is correct. Data for each returned array is 2018, 2018, 3010, 3010, 3614, 3614, 1816, 1816, 1812 and 1812. The reason for duplicate numbers is each axle has 2 tires. The data is broken down with first 2 digits being the week and second 2 digits being the year the tire was manufactured.
Thanks for all help provided. My code is as follows:

```
func updateDOTCodes() {
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var myDOTTFArray: [String] {
        return [classALFDOTNumber.text!, classARFDOTNumber.text!, classALRDualOutsideDOTNumber.text!, classARRDualOutsideDOTNumber.text!, classALRDualInsideDOTNumber.text!, classARRDualInsideDOTNumber.text!, classALRDualOutsideTagAxleDOTNumber.text!, classARRDualOutsideTagAxleDOTNumber.text!, classALRDualInsideTagAxleDOTNumber.text!, classARRDualInsideTagAxleDOTNumber.text!]
    }
    
    for counter in 0...myDOTTFArray.count-1 {
        let myString = myDOTTFArray[counter]
        
        if myString != "" {
            
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YY"
            let yearString = Int(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
            let startIndex = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
            let endIndex = myString.index(myString.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
            
            let tireWeek = Int(String(myString.prefix(upTo: startIndex)))
            let tireYear = Int(String(myString.suffix(from: endIndex)))
            
            if currentWeek >= tireWeek! && yearString! - 5 <= tireYear! {
                print(myString + " Green")
            }
            
            if currentWeek <= tireWeek! && yearString! - 5 >= tireYear! && yearString! - 7 <= tireYear! {
                print(myString + " Yellow")
                // Insert code here to change myString text to Orange as Yellow does not display well
            }
            
            if currentWeek >= tireWeek! &&  yearString! - 7 >= tireYear! {
                print(myString + " Red")
                // Insert code here to change myString text to red
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: myString is a variable but not an UI Element like UILabel or UIButton. So can you clarify color of which UI element is to be updated?

Comment: What is `currentWeek`?

Comment: Current week is 2 characters from  let currentWeek = Int(NSCalendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date())) declared just after class statement.

Comment: Color to be updated is when I perform my loop and the criteria of the "if" statement is met I want to change the font color. For example first time through the loop data is 2018 which is less than the year String! - 5 so color of 2018 should change to green.

Comment: To clarify all fields in the array have IBOutlets by the same name. For example first item in the array is classALFDOTNumber.text! and IBOutlet holding the test data is classALFDOTNumber as UITextField. The third iteration of the loop the test data is 3010 which when evaluated should change 3010 font to red. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the `text` values iterate the `UITextField` instances and set the text color if the text field accordingly

```
func updateDOTCodes() {
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YY"
    
    var myDOTTFArray: [UITextField] {
        return [classALFDOTNumber, classARFDOTNumber, classALRDualOutsideDOTNumber, classARRDualOutsideDOTNumber, classALRDualInsideDOTNumber, classARRDualInsideDOTNumber, classALRDualOutsideTagAxleDOTNumber, classARRDualOutsideTagAxleDOTNumber, classALRDualInsideTagAxleDOTNumber, classARRDualInsideTagAxleDOTNumber]
    }
    
    for textField in myDOTTFArray {
        
        if let myString = textField.text, !myString.isEmpty,
           let tireWeek = Int(myString.prefix(2)),
           let tireYear = Int(myString.suffix(2)) { 
          
            let yearString = Int(dateFormatter.string(from: date))!
    
            
            if currentWeek >= tireWeek && yearString - 5 <= tireYear {
                textField.textColor = .systemGreen
            }
            
            if currentWeek <= tireWeek && yearString - 5 >= tireYear && yearString - 7 <= tireYear {
                textField.textColor = .systemOrange
            }
            
            if currentWeek >= tireWeek &&  yearString - 7 >= tireYear {
                textField.textColor = .systemRed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! Works like a charm. Thank you so much. New to Swift and this helps immensely. One error in your code you have yearString! -5 in systemOrange block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing textColor on the label that shows the text - instead of the String:

```
label.textColor = .green
```

Comment: Please clarify how I determine which label is current. For example during the 5th iteration of the loop the data is 3614 so how do I determine it came fromclassALRDualInsideDOTNumber.text! to change the color to red.